BTC to LND Node Transfer Not Showing yet on node's wallet after almost two weeks?
I realize that this may or may not be a question to ask of the Umbrel developers but I have to sadly report to you all that they rarely answer any posts on their forum.
Please help us with this situation if you can. We sent BTC from Bitfinex to our Electrum Wallet on our Windows PC which has shown up in the Electrum's history to then be sent
directly over tor (blue icon was active) to our Lightning Node (using Umbrel) which we have done many times now but this time it still has not arrived in our nodes BTC wallet
yet after almost two weeks and over 2340 confirmations, as seen on mempool.
https://mempool.space/tx/97fdb66ab006da2c634f77f8dfa66d959609517a15878266c67b9686a9866894
Any ideas as to why it has yet to reach our node's wallet? BTW we sent a 2nd amount of BTC again using Bitfinex to our Electrum Wallet last Friday and that has also not shown
up on our node's BTC wallet and yes it is recognized in the Electrum wallet on the PC but not on the node?  Thank you for any assiatance anyone can offer us to try and fix this problem :)
Oh BTW our Electrum wallet has not reported any issues.

Hi all, Am I possibly missing a step due to old age? Please let me know. Thank you.

Is your Umbrel-hosted lightning node the on-chain recipient of the transaction you listed?

Hi RedGrittyBrick, Thank you for your reply. Well no i guess not I was under the wrong impression due to a faulty memory I suppose that our Electrum wallet on our PC (Which is connected via tor to the Electrum Server app on our Umbrel LND Node) would send the funds to the Umbrel node via the Electrum server app automatucally once we sent the Electrum wallet some BTC from our exchange account after a period of time? I seemed to remember it doing this before but I guess I was wrong? Thank you.
